# Optimize MySQL query using multiple joins by order on logging table to find greatest diff (best records)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, window-functions

Suppose that we have a table to log users' weights and other info as follows:

```
health_indexes

id | user_id | weight | created_at
---+---------+--------+-----------
1  | 50      | 100    | 2020-01-01
2  | 50      | 98     | 2020-01-05
3  | 50      | 98.5   | 2020-01-10
4  | 50      | 92     | 2020-01-15
5  | 50      | 80     | 2020-01-20
.
.
.
10 | 100     | 130    | 2018-01-01
11 | 100     | 149999 | 2018-01-05
12 | 100     | 159999 | 2018-01-10
13 | 100     | 120    | 2018-01-15
.
.
.
20 | 200     | 87     | 2020-02-01
.
.
.
30 | 300     | 140    | 2020-01-01
```

I do get to the following table, but I'm looking for a better way:

```
user_id | first_weight | first_created_at | last_weight | last_created_at
--------+--------------+------------------+-------------+----------------
50      | 100          | 2020-01-01       | 80          | 2020-01-20
100     | 130          | 2018-01-01       | 120         | 2018-01-15
```

Query:

```
select u.id user_id,
    (select weight from health_indexes where user_id = u.id order by created_at limit 1) first_weight,
    (select created_at from health_indexes where user_id = u.id order by created_at limit 1) first_created_at,
    (select weight from health_indexes where user_id = u.id order by created_at desc limit 1) last_weight,
    (select created_at from health_indexes where user_id = u.id order by created_at desc limit 1) last_created_at
from users u
group by u.id
having first_weight > last_weight
order by (first_weight - last_weight) desc
limit 50;
```

I'm looking for a way to JOIN twice on health_indexes to get the same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions only, without any join. There is one of the rare cases when `distinct` can be usefuly combined with window functions:

```
select distinct
    user_id,
    first_value(weight) over(partition by user_id order by created_at)       first_weight,
    min(created_at)     over(partition by user_id)                           first_created_at,
    first_value(weight) over(partition by user_id order by created_at desc)  last_weight,
    max(created_at)     over(partition by user_id)                           last_created_at
from health_indexes
```

In earlier versions, one options uses joins and filtering:

```
select 
    hi1.user_id,
    hi1.weight first_weight,
    hi1.created_at first_created_at,
    hi2.weight last_weight,
    hi2.created_at last_created_at
from health_indexes hi1
inner join health_indexes hi2 on hi2.user_id = hi1.user_id
where
        hi1.created_at = (select min(h3.created_at) from health_indexes hi3 where hi3.user_id = hi1.user_id)
    and hi2.created_at = (select max(h3.created_at) from health_indexes hi3 where hi3.user_id = hi2.user_id)
```

Comment: Umm... new things to learn.... :thinking:, I will try your solution, thanks @GMB

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by user_id order by created_at)       first_weight,
    min(created_a' at line 3

Comment: @MohammadNaji: this indicates that your sql version is < 8.0. I updated my answer with a solution for MySQL < 8.0